# Running Clockwork and Delayed Job on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job, bluepill

I am migrating my existing rails app to heroku. I have memory and time intensive delayed jobs that run almost 20 hours a day and I have a clockwork to handle the time specific jobs. the clockwork jobs are not so heavy and run a very few times in one day.

Is is possible to run both the delayed job process and the clockwork process using a single heroku process using bluepill ?

I do not want to pay for one more worker just for the sake of clockwork processes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [heroku scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler), it will allow you to schedule jobs on a daily, hourly or 10 minute interval.